# Use congruences to factor $n=87463$ (Fermat's Factorization?)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization, totient-function

I'm studying for my number theory test tomorrow, and these are the last questions in my study guide. I think I understand Fermat's factorization, however, I can't tell how my professor wants us to answer these questions. One of them is going to be on the exam.

1. Set $n= 87463$ and $q(x) = x^2 - n$. Explain how to use the congruences
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   q(265) &=& -2\times3\times13^2\times17,\\
   q(278) &=& -3^3\times13\times29,\\
   q(296) &=&  3^2\times17,\\
   q(299) &=&  2\times3\times17\times19,\\
   q(307) &=&  2\times3^2\times13\times29,\\
   q(316) &=&  3^6\times17,
   \end{eqnarray*}
   to factor $n$.
2. Explain how the congruences below prove that $n = 2821$ is composite
   \begin{eqnarray*}
   2^{705}  &=& 2605 \pmod n,\\
   2^{1410} &=& 1520 \pmod n,\\
   2^{2820} &=& 1    \pmod n.
   \end{eqnarray*}
   I'm not so sure if these questions are related or not. In the second one, it is easy to see $705 = \frac{n-1}4$, $1410 = \frac{n-1}{2}$ and $2820 = n-1$ however I'm not sure on which property to use here.

Comment: You don't say what the modulus is in the first group of congruences.

Comment: @David The first few equations are not congruences.

Comment: @Servaes Then I don't see how $q(296)$ and $q(299)$ can be equal integers.

Comment: The first question actually doesn't deal with congruences. I thought the two questions were related, but maybe they aren't. (Oh sorry David the 299 part was a typo)

Comment: @Jake please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset math.

Comment: I tried, and I will in the future. Can we get back to the questions please, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It is probably better to write $(n-1)/4$ or $\frac{n-1)4$ than to write $n-1/4$. The latter would mean $2821-1/4=2820.75$, which is not an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, you can factor $n$ by using $q(316) = 3^4 q(296)$.

For the second part, if $n$ were prime, then $Z/nZ$ would be a field, so the congruence $x^2 = 1$ would have only two solutions. But you have another solution staring you right in the face.

Comment: Ah, okay I think I see the answer for the second question; thanks for the advice. So if I choose \begin{eqnarray*}
x = 2^{705}
\end{eqnarray*} Then $x^2$ is not equal to 1 mod n, thus n is composite.

Comment: No, that's wrong. What are the solutions of the equation $x^2 = 1$ in a ring with no zero divisors?

Comment: Just 1 and -1, right? I meant above that $x^2$ is not equal to 1 or -1

Comment: Right, $1$ and $-1$. But you don't want an $x$ such that $x^2 \ne \pm 1$. You want an $x$ such that $x^2 = 1$ but $x \ne \pm 1$.

Comment: Oh that's right. So essentially ignore the first part and let \begin{eqnarray*}
x &=& 2^{1410} &=& 1520,
\end{eqnarray*}
then $x^2$ = 1

Comment: Right. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to use Fermat's factorization. The given factorizations of $q(296)$ and $q(316)$ differ by a factor $3^4$, which is a square. This allows us to write
$$n=316^2-3^6\times17=316^2-3^4\times(3^2\times17)=316^2-3^4\times(296^2-n).$$
Isolating $n$ yields $(1-3^4)n=316^2-3^4\times296^2$, or equivalently
$$2^4\times5\times n=3^4\times296^2-316^2=2^4\times\left((3^2\times74)^2-79^2\right).$$
Taking out the factor $2^4$ then leaves $5\times n$ as a difference of squares:
$$5\times n=(3^2\times74)^2-79^2=666^2-79^2.$$
Then Fermat's factorization tells us that $5\times n=587\times745$, giving the factorization
$$n=149\times587.$$

Comment: Thank you, I understand this all except for the line following "or equivalently". I'm not seeing how that left side is equal to (1-$3^4$)n

Comment: It's not supposed to be, it's supposed to be equal to the opposite.

Comment: Right, yeah, I see how the right side negation is true... But not how ($3^4$-1)n = $2^4$ x 5 x n (please excuse my notation). Edit: Nevermind, I see that they both equal 80... Yes this makes more sense now, well done :)